# .html property updates once once

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have following divs

```
<div id="daily" style="display:none">
   <p class="scheduleData">Every <input type="text" data-bind="value:EveryNPeriods"/> days      
</div>

<div id="weekly" style="display:none">
     <p class="scheduleData">Recur Every <input type="text" data-bind="value:EveryNPeriods" style="width:20px; "/>Week(s) on: </p><br/>
</div>
```

I have a drop down which contains Daily and Weekly options. On dropdown change I must be able to load the contents of the other div. Here is my code for this:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var selected = $("#dropdown").val();
    if (selected == "Daily") {
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html("");
        //$("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#daily").html());
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#daily").contents());
    } else if (selected == "Weekly") {
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html("");
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#weekly").contents());

});
```

The problem is DivTobeLoaded gets updated only once for each dropdown option (For example, first time I change it to Weekly, div gets loaded with the contents of weekly div. If I now change it to Daily, it gets loaded. But then when I switch back to Weekly, div does not load). If I use .html instead of .contents it works fine. But I am loosing all my knockout bindings if I use .html property as it creates new nodes.

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket for your **else if** statement.

Comment: And why you just don't display this div which you need? And hide another?

Comment: @pmandell closing bracket is a typo.. I have that in my code.

Comment: Try with this: `var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();` instead of `var selected = $("#dropdown").val();`

Comment: @PalashMondal: Thanks for the suggestion but it din work :(

Answer (score 0):

Close the else loop wth '}'

```
var selected = $("#dropdown option:selected").val();    //Try this also
if (selected == "Daily") {
    $("#DivToBeLoaded").html("");
    //$("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#daily").html());
    $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#daily").contents());
} else if (selected == "Weekly") {
    $("#DivToBeLoaded").html("");
    $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#weekly").contents());
}  //end of else if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with just if eles

$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#DivToBeLoaded").html("");//Make blank here
    if (selected == "Daily") {
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#daily").contents());
    } else {
        $("#DivToBeLoaded").html($("#weekly").contents());
    }
});
```